# Is RxJS Memory efficient in the case described below?

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

Lets consider an Observable

```
let obs = Rx.Observable
.interval(1000)
.take(3);

obs.subscribe(value => console.log("Subscriber: " + value));
```

This will yield me

```
Subscriber: 0
Subscriber: 1
Subscriber: 2
```

But, does interval operator creates new stream value for every second? Resulting in increase in memory every second? Although, take operator takes only first 3 values.

Comment: What do you mean by stream value? It emits just numbers.

Comment: @martin Yeah, was referring to that. Does it emits numbers even though I control them using take operator?

Comment: It emits 3 valeus and then the chain is disposed which means everything unsubscribes from everything and in turn `interval()` is stopped.